# MVC 4 converting to one element list with null

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following DTO on Server Side:

```
 public SearchDTO {

 public IList<SortOrder> MultiSearchSort {
            get; set;
        }
}
```

On the client side, I´m passing undefined on the multiSearchSort json:

```
searchDTO.multiSearchSort:
```

On the server, MultiSearchSort is being populated with a one-element array with a null value.

The same call to a WebAPI doesn´t produce that effect (i.e I get a null List on server side as I would expect)

Is there any mapping that needs to be done especifically for MVC calls so that undefined json arrays remains null on server side?

Thanks